# Statistical comparison of clustered variables

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, nested-models

I have a data set consisting of 50 measurements of cytokine concentrations in 70 patients, resulting in a (70, 50) data frame. In addition, I have a data set containing covariables related to the samples (e.g. demographic data for this particular patient population). We grouped the cytokine measurements into biologically meaningful signatures (clusters). As such, there is already variance around the signature values for each individual patient. We calculate the signature value as the average of cytokine concentrations. One signature consists of multiple cytokines and they are non-overlapping.

My question is, how can I compare the difference in terms of the signatures between two groups of patients (say, male vs female), considering the distributions I want to compare consist of averages with a standard deviation.

Which statistical test would be appropriate here? Is there such a thing as a nested t-test or should I look for alternative strategies such as nested ANOVA or mixed models?

Comment: What do you mean by "As such, there is already variance around the signature values for each individual patient." ?

Comment: Sorry, this is perhaps not clearly formulated. Since the cytokine values are clustered by averaging across them, the signatures essentially just describe the distribution of the underlying cytokine values.

Comment: What exactly do you wish to learn from this data? Just whether groups are different based on some statistical criterion? Are the groups/clusters defined based on  different criteria such as sex or are the clusters created based on the cytokine measurements?

Comment: Groups are based on characteristics of the cytokines, not the patients. We want to learn whether there is a difference in the expression of certain signatures between two patient groups (e.g. sex, early/late disease onset, etc.)